# Should I call destructor by myself

Tags: c#, azure, memory-management, destructor

If I'm 100% sure that I will no longer use an object, whichever (or how large) it may be, as a caring developer, penny pinching my way into azure hosting, should I invoke it's destructor by myself or should I leave it, delegating it to the G.C?

Details:

- I really need to squeeze as many apps on a machine as possible
- My applications are already on 32bit platform to save memory
- Diagnostics show that response times is highly affected by G.C. running
- Already implementing other penny pinching techs
- I don't mind doing it, and only intend to do it for objects that are not under the DI container control

Comment: If type has finalizer - it should implement IDisposable with Dispose method you have to call in your case.

Comment: By the way as I remember you cannot even call destructor manually, how are you going to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "destructor" of an object that will *release memory* used by the object, so strictly speaking - no, you don't need to call destructor by yourself (even if you could) to achieve your goals. Garbage collection is the only thing that actually can free up memory used by an object.

What you should do:

- dispose `IDisposable` objects
- consider forcing GC at times when you find acceptable.

Additional ideas:

- profile to understand what type of objects get collected the most and overall what types put pressure on GC.
- consider not to keep objects alive for average amount of time (prefer very short or very long lifetime), keep long-lived objects unmodified (prefer completely immutable objects to cache values for long time)
- read on other things impacting GC effectiveness (like pinned buffers).